# MySQL Query Limitation on OR and IN clauses

Tags: mysql

We have a pricing table which store the pricing information indexed against four attributes(store_id, fee_type, business_line, variant).

```
CREATE TABLE `pricing_info` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `business_line` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `fee_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `variant` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fee_config` text,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `store_fee_business_variant` (`store_id`,`fee_type`,`business_line`,`variant`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2268 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In the Application layer, we get call for multiple store-id which is translated to sample query like this to DB:

Query using IN clauses:

```
select * from pricing_info where store_id IN (store_id1, store_id2, ......, store_id400) and fee_type = 'Distance' and business_line = 'Default';
```

Query using OR clauses:

```
select * from pricing_info where 
(store_id = store_id1 and fee_type = 'Distance' and business_line = 'Default') OR
(store_id = store_id2 and fee_type = 'Distance' and business_line = 'Default') OR
......
(store_id = store_id400 and fee_type = 'Distance' and business_line = 'Default');
```

Problem:
In the OR/IN clauses index(store_fee_business_variant) is getting used till 400 store_ID, but beyond that it goes to full table scan. So, question is how does MySQL decides when to move from Index to Full table scan based on the size of the query?

Additional Info for the table and index:
Number of rows(pricing_info): 2266
Size of index: 0.16 MB (by querying mysql.innodb_index_stats)
Number of pages in index: 10 (by querying mysql.innodb_index_stats)
Number of leaf pages in index: 9 (by querying mysql.innodb_index_stats)

Comment: How will knowing this help?

Comment: If there is a way to know the limitation(X number of clauses for index to be used), then we can make changes to the Application layer to makes call with X number of clauses, rather then sending all store-id in one go.

Comment: Well, that seems like a slightly different question to me, and one to which you already know the answer!

Comment: But if I had circa 400 values for comparison, I would just load them into a table and join that to the query

Comment: Question is the logic used by query planner for number(400) clauses when switching from index to full table scan, given the size of table(2266 rows) and index size(0.16 MB).